# How to stop the box bouncing and stretching in this `ListAnimate`?

Tags: animation

I want to stop the bouncing and stretching of this `Graphic3D`?

do I need to experiment with `AspectRatio -> SomeFunction`?

```
ListAnimate[
    Table[
        Graphics3D[
            Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}],
            AspectRatio -> 1,
            PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {1, 2}, {-2, 2}},
            ViewVector -> {5 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t], 10 Sin[t/2]}],
         {t, 0, 4 \[Pi], .1}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Is `SphericalRegion -> True` enough?

Comment: @Kuba works like a charm!!